# What does "throw the dog on the curb" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "throw the dog on the curb" mean here?

> So Heather, she can't talk to her friends because she's afraid that they will judge her for still loving Nick, and everywhere she turns, she gets the same advice: Leave him. **Throw the dog on the curb**. And if the situation were reversed, Nick would be in the same situation. Staying is the new shame.

Source: [TED Talk by Esther Perel](https://www.ted.com/talks/esther_perel_rethinking_infidelity_a_talk_for_anyone_who_has_ever_loved/transcript?language=en#t-549977), "Rethinking infidelity ... a talk for anyone who has ever loved"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a mish-mash of the idioms *[Throw him out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw-sb-out)*, *Put the dog out*, and *[Kick him to the curb](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kick+him+to+the+curb)*, all filtered through the mind of Esther Perel. Ms Perel is fluent in English, and if you follow the link in the OP, I don't doubt you'll find her an engaging, even eloquent speaker. She was born in Belgium, went to school in Israel, and now lives and works in New York; accordingly her idiomatic usages are sometimes slightly unusual.

She means that Heather should terminate her relationship with Nick.

Comment: Since it says _throw the dog **on** the curb_, rather than _**to** the curb_, there may even be a bit of “throw him out on the street” in there. A lovely little mishmash!

Comment: There's also the derogatory element in referring to a human being as a dog.